# Xvfb -screen --> (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets

Tags: ubuntu, wine, games, xvfb

I'm trying to run a gameserver for the game "Insurgency: Modern Infantry Combat" on a VPS rented from Kimsufi running Ubuntu 15.10.

I've had prior experience messing around with Wine and Xvfb but right now I'm unsure of how to continue and solve these issues. I need to use Wine and Xvfb as I'm trying to run a Windows-based gameserver on my VPS because the Linux version of the gameserver is horribly broken and has no chance of being fixed because of the developer releasing a new Insurgency game back in 2014.

Here's the startup script I did for the server. I have to do things this way because there's no physical "screen" for the VPS, and I don't know how to make it use my own desktop as a "screen" to display things.

```
#!/bin/bash
Xvfb :1&
export DISPLAY=:1
wine start srcds.exe -console -secure -game insurgency +map ins_karam +rcon_password RdbtTc5CR4QrjZiQirhp -strictportbind -port 27050 +clientport 27150 +tv_port 27155 -maxplayers 32 +sv_master_legacy_mode 0 &
```

And here's what I'm getting spat out at me every time I try to start the server.

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
fixme:keyboard:X11DRV_LoadKeyboardLayout L"00000409", 0000: stub!
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33d720 (nil)): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33d0dc (nil)): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0xf09e03c (nil)): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0xf29e9e8 (nil)): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33d488 (nil)): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0xfde5b30, 0xfe1ab30, 0xfe1ab28
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0xfde5b30, 0xfe1ab68, 0xfe1ab60
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0xfde5b30, 0xfe1aaf8, 0xfe1aaf0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0xfde5b30, 0xfe1aba0, 0xfe1ab98
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0xfde5b30, 0xfe1abd8, 0xfe1abd0
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

Not sure what to do here. If you guys need any additional info, just let me know.

Answer (score 5):

> (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
>   fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored:

Either there is an Xfvb (or another X server) already running on display :1 or there are some lock files left from a previous run.

See `ls -l  /tmp/.X*` and look at your process list `ps aux | grep -i xvfb`.

In case another X is running you may kill it. Or manually delete the `X1*` lock files. Or choose another display for you Xvfb (`Xvfb :123`).

Your start script should make sure to kill the X server on exit. Otherwise you could also re-use the Xvfb session if it's already running.

**FYI** I have such a `Xvfb/wine` script running in production. Although also not perfect it always run without any problems since years via cron. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

VNC_PORT=29
export DISPLAY=":${VNC_PORT}.0"

/usr/bin/Xvfb :${VNC_PORT} -screen 0 1024x768x8 -fbdir /var/tmp  &
XVFB_PID=$!

# waiting for XServer  established (or failure)
sleep 1

if test "${XVFB_PID}" != "$(jobs -p)" ;then
    echo "error, Xvfb failed"
    exit 1
fi

/usr/bin/wine **your command**
RET=$?
echo "wine returned '$RET'"

# waiting for shutdown all wine stuff completely
sleep 2

kill $XVFB_PID
exit $RET
```